# Spark streaming 2.11 - java.util.NoSuchElementException: None.get error when executing SQL function

Tags: java, apache-spark, exception, spark-structured-streaming, nosuchelementexception

#### Issue

I'm using Spark to join the contents of CSV files.

After I do the first join, with the streamed CSV file I am able to write the stream with no error and can see it has many rows were output, but once I try to write my second stream I get an error message.

#### Code

```
SparkSession spark = SparkSession
            .builder()
            .appName("MySparkApp")
            .config("spark.master", "local")
            .getOrCreate();
Dataset<Row> dfOne= spark.read().schema(stForOne).csv(pathToOne);
Dataset<Row> dfTwo = spark.read().schema(stForTwo).csv(pathToTwo).dropDuplicates("num1");
Dataset<Row> dfThree= spark.read().option("header","true").csv(pathToThree);
Dataset<Row> dfStreamed = spark.readStream().option("comment", "!").schema(stForStreamed).csv(pathToStreamed);

dfOne.createOrReplaceTempView("viewOne");
dfTwo.createOrReplaceTempView("viewTwo");
dfThree.createOrReplaceTempView("viewThree");
dfStreamed.createOrReplaceTempView("viewStreamed");


Dataset<Row> changedOnce = spark.sql("SELECT * FROM viewStreamed LEFT JOIN viewOne ON viewStreamed.name = viewOne.Name");
changedOnce.createOrReplaceTempView("viewStreamed")

Dataset<Row> changedTwice = spark.sql("SELECT * FROM viewStreamed LEFT JOIN viewTwo ON viewStreamed.NUM1 = viewTwo.num1"); 

StreamingQuery query = changedTwice.writeStream()
            .outputMode("append")
            .format("console")
            .start(); 

    try {
        query.awaitTermination();
    } catch (StreamingQueryException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    query.stop();
```

#### Error Message

```
18/07/16 14:26:05 ERROR Executor: Exception in task 0.0 in stage 36.0 (TID 609)
java.util.NoSuchElementException: None.get
    at scala.None$.get(Option.scala:347)
    at scala.None$.get(Option.scala:345)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.StateStoreSaveExec$$anonfun$doExecute$3.apply(StatefulAggregate.scala:187)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.StateStoreSaveExec$$anonfun$doExecute$3.apply(StatefulAggregate.scala:148)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.state.StateStoreRDD.compute(StateStoreRDD.scala:64)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:323)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:287)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:38)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:323)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:287)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:38)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:323)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:287)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:38)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:323)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:287)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:87)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:99)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:322)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
18/07/16 14:26:05 INFO TaskSetManager: Starting task 1.0 in stage 36.0 (TID 610, localhost, executor driver, partition 1, PROCESS_LOCAL, 6075 bytes)
18/07/16 14:26:05 INFO Executor: Running task 1.0 in stage 36.0 (TID 610)
18/07/16 14:26:05 WARN TaskSetManager: Lost task 0.0 in stage 36.0 (TID 609, localhost, executor driver): java.util.NoSuchElementException: None.get
    at scala.None$.get(Option.scala:347)
    at scala.None$.get(Option.scala:345)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.StateStoreSaveExec$$anonfun$doExecute$3.apply(StatefulAggregate.scala:187)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.StateStoreSaveExec$$anonfun$doExecute$3.apply(StatefulAggregate.scala:148)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.state.StateStoreRDD.compute(StateStoreRDD.scala:64)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:323)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:287)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:38)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:323)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:287)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:38)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:323)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:287)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:38)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:323)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:287)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:87)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:99)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:322)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

18/07/16 14:26:05 ERROR TaskSetManager: Task 0 in stage 36.0 failed 1 times; aborting job
18/07/16 14:26:05 INFO TaskSchedulerImpl: Cancelling stage 36
18/07/16 14:26:05 INFO Executor: Executor is trying to kill task 1.0 in stage 36.0 (TID 610)
18/07/16 14:26:05 INFO TaskSchedulerImpl: Stage 36 was cancelled
18/07/16 14:26:05 INFO DAGScheduler: ResultStage 36 (start at App.java:308) failed in 0.149 s due to Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 0 in stage 36.0 failed 1 times, most recent failure: Lost task 0.0 in stage 36.0 (TID 609, localhost, executor driver): java.util.NoSuchElementException: None.get
    at scala.None$.get(Option.scala:347)
    at scala.None$.get(Option.scala:345)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.StateStoreSaveExec$$anonfun$doExecute$3.apply(StatefulAggregate.scala:187)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.StateStoreSaveExec$$anonfun$doExecute$3.apply(StatefulAggregate.scala:148)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.state.StateStoreRDD.compute(StateStoreRDD.scala:64)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:323)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:287)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:38)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:323)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:287)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:38)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:323)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:287)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:38)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:323)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:287)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:87)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:99)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:322)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

Driver stacktrace:
18/07/16 14:26:05 INFO HDFSBackedStateStoreProvider: Retrieved version 0 of HDFSStateStoreProvider[id = (op=0, part=1), dir = C:/Users/am818j/AppData/Local/Temp/temporary-55bfe531-c60d-411d-ab5a-94c11f79910e/state/0/1] for update
18/07/16 14:26:05 INFO HDFSBackedStateStoreProvider: Retrieved version 0 of HDFSStateStoreProvider[id = (op=0, part=1), dir = C:/Users/am818j/AppData/Local/Temp/temporary-55bfe531-c60d-411d-ab5a-94c11f79910e/state/0/1] for update
18/07/16 14:26:05 INFO ShuffleBlockFetcherIterator: Getting 0 non-empty blocks out of 1 blocks
18/07/16 14:26:05 INFO ShuffleBlockFetcherIterator: Started 0 remote fetches in 1 ms
18/07/16 14:26:05 INFO DAGScheduler: Job 20 failed: start at App.java:308, took 0.262841 s
18/07/16 14:26:05 INFO Executor: Executor killed task 1.0 in stage 36.0 (TID 610)
18/07/16 14:26:05 WARN TaskSetManager: Lost task 1.0 in stage 36.0 (TID 610, localhost, executor driver): TaskKilled (killed intentionally)
18/07/16 14:26:05 INFO TaskSchedulerImpl: Removed TaskSet 36.0, whose tasks have all completed, from pool 
18/07/16 14:26:05 ERROR StreamExecution: Query [id = 60f7c698-7093-495a-bec8-5cdec7a06f69, runId = 6f533a5f-8891-4daf-bd21-79db292283c5] terminated with error
org.apache.spark.SparkException: Exception thrown in awaitResult: 
    at org.apache.spark.util.ThreadUtils$.awaitResultInForkJoinSafely(ThreadUtils.scala:215)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.exchange.BroadcastExchangeExec.doExecuteBroadcast(BroadcastExchangeExec.scala:125)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.InputAdapter.doExecuteBroadcast(WholeStageCodegenExec.scala:231)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$executeBroadcast$1.apply(SparkPlan.scala:124)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$executeBroadcast$1.apply(SparkPlan.scala:124)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$executeQuery$1.apply(SparkPlan.scala:135)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:151)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.executeQuery(SparkPlan.scala:132)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.executeBroadcast(SparkPlan.scala:123)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.joins.BroadcastHashJoinExec.prepareBroadcast(BroadcastHashJoinExec.scala:98)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.joins.BroadcastHashJoinExec.codegenOuter(BroadcastHashJoinExec.scala:242)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.joins.BroadcastHashJoinExec.doConsume(BroadcastHashJoinExec.scala:83)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.CodegenSupport$class.consume(WholeStageCodegenExec.scala:153)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.ProjectExec.consume(basicPhysicalOperators.scala:36)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.ProjectExec.doConsume(basicPhysicalOperators.scala:68)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.CodegenSupport$class.consume(WholeStageCodegenExec.scala:153)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.joins.BroadcastHashJoinExec.consume(BroadcastHashJoinExec.scala:38)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.joins.BroadcastHashJoinExec.codegenOuter(BroadcastHashJoinExec.scala:308)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.joins.BroadcastHashJoinExec.doConsume(BroadcastHashJoinExec.scala:83)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.CodegenSupport$class.consume(WholeStageCodegenExec.scala:153)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.FileSourceScanExec.consume(DataSourceScanExec.scala:141)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.FileSourceScanExec.doProduce(DataSourceScanExec.scala:333)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.CodegenSupport$$anonfun$produce$1.apply(WholeStageCodegenExec.scala:83)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.CodegenSupport$$anonfun$produce$1.apply(WholeStageCodegenExec.scala:78)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$executeQuery$1.apply(SparkPlan.scala:135)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:151)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.executeQuery(SparkPlan.scala:132)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.CodegenSupport$class.produce(WholeStageCodegenExec.scala:78)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.FileSourceScanExec.produce(DataSourceScanExec.scala:141)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.joins.BroadcastHashJoinExec.doProduce(BroadcastHashJoinExec.scala:77)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.CodegenSupport$$anonfun$produce$1.apply(WholeStageCodegenExec.scala:83)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.CodegenSupport$$anonfun$produce$1.apply(WholeStageCodegenExec.scala:78)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$executeQuery$1.apply(SparkPlan.scala:135)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:151)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.executeQuery(SparkPlan.scala:132)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.CodegenSupport$class.produce(WholeStageCodegenExec.scala:78)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.joins.BroadcastHashJoinExec.produce(BroadcastHashJoinExec.scala:38)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.ProjectExec.doProduce(basicPhysicalOperators.scala:46)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.CodegenSupport$$anonfun$produce$1.apply(WholeStageCodegenExec.scala:83)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.CodegenSupport$$anonfun$produce$1.apply(WholeStageCodegenExec.scala:78)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$executeQuery$1.apply(SparkPlan.scala:135)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:151)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.executeQuery(SparkPlan.scala:132)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.CodegenSupport$class.produce(WholeStageCodegenExec.scala:78)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.ProjectExec.produce(basicPhysicalOperators.scala:36)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.joins.BroadcastHashJoinExec.doProduce(BroadcastHashJoinExec.scala:77)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.CodegenSupport$$anonfun$produce$1.apply(WholeStageCodegenExec.scala:83)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.CodegenSupport$$anonfun$produce$1.apply(WholeStageCodegenExec.scala:78)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$executeQuery$1.apply(SparkPlan.scala:135)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:151)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.executeQuery(SparkPlan.scala:132)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.CodegenSupport$class.produce(WholeStageCodegenExec.scala:78)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.joins.BroadcastHashJoinExec.produce(BroadcastHashJoinExec.scala:38)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.WholeStageCodegenExec.doCodeGen(WholeStageCodegenExec.scala:313)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.WholeStageCodegenExec.doExecute(WholeStageCodegenExec.scala:354)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$execute$1.apply(SparkPlan.scala:114)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$execute$1.apply(SparkPlan.scala:114)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$executeQuery$1.apply(SparkPlan.scala:135)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:151)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.executeQuery(SparkPlan.scala:132)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.execute(SparkPlan.scala:113)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.getByteArrayRdd(SparkPlan.scala:225)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.executeCollect(SparkPlan.scala:272)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$sql$Dataset$$execute$1$1.apply(Dataset.scala:2386)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withNewExecutionId(SQLExecution.scala:57)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.withNewExecutionId(Dataset.scala:2788)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.org$apache$spark$sql$Dataset$$execute$1(Dataset.scala:2385)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$sql$Dataset$$collect$1.apply(Dataset.scala:2390)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$sql$Dataset$$collect$1.apply(Dataset.scala:2390)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.withCallback(Dataset.scala:2801)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.org$apache$spark$sql$Dataset$$collect(Dataset.scala:2390)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.collect(Dataset.scala:2366)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.ConsoleSink.addBatch(console.scala:49)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.StreamExecution$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$sql$execution$streaming$StreamExecution$$runBatch$1.apply$mcV$sp(StreamExecution.scala:554)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.StreamExecution$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$sql$execution$streaming$StreamExecution$$runBatch$1.apply(StreamExecution.scala:554)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.StreamExecution$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$sql$execution$streaming$StreamExecution$$runBatch$1.apply(StreamExecution.scala:554)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.ProgressReporter$class.reportTimeTaken(ProgressReporter.scala:278)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.StreamExecution.reportTimeTaken(StreamExecution.scala:49)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.StreamExecution.org$apache$spark$sql$execution$streaming$StreamExecution$$runBatch(StreamExecution.scala:553)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.StreamExecution$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$sql$execution$streaming$StreamExecution$$runBatches$1$$anonfun$1.apply$mcV$sp(StreamExecution.scala:273)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.StreamExecution$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$sql$execution$streaming$StreamExecution$$runBatches$1$$anonfun$1.apply(StreamExecution.scala:262)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.StreamExecution$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$sql$execution$streaming$StreamExecution$$runBatches$1$$anonfun$1.apply(StreamExecution.scala:262)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.ProgressReporter$class.reportTimeTaken(ProgressReporter.scala:278)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.StreamExecution.reportTimeTaken(StreamExecution.scala:49)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.StreamExecution$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$sql$execution$streaming$StreamExecution$$runBatches$1.apply$mcZ$sp(StreamExecution.scala:262)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.ProcessingTimeExecutor.execute(TriggerExecutor.scala:43)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.StreamExecution.org$apache$spark$sql$execution$streaming$StreamExecution$$runBatches(StreamExecution.scala:257)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.StreamExecution$$anon$1.run(StreamExecution.scala:191)
Caused by: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 0 in stage 36.0 failed 1 times, most recent failure: Lost task 0.0 in stage 36.0 (TID 609, localhost, executor driver): java.util.NoSuchElementException: None.get
    at scala.None$.get(Option.scala:347)
    at scala.None$.get(Option.scala:345)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.StateStoreSaveExec$$anonfun$doExecute$3.apply(StatefulAggregate.scala:187)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.StateStoreSaveExec$$anonfun$doExecute$3.apply(StatefulAggregate.scala:148)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.state.StateStoreRDD.compute(StateStoreRDD.scala:64)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:323)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:287)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:38)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:323)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:287)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:38)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:323)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:287)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:38)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:323)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:287)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:87)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:99)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:322)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

Driver stacktrace:
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.org$apache$spark$scheduler$DAGScheduler$$failJobAndIndependentStages(DAGScheduler.scala:1435)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1423)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1422)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray$class.foreach(ResizableArray.scala:59)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.foreach(ArrayBuffer.scala:48)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.abortStage(DAGScheduler.scala:1422)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:802)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:802)
    at scala.Option.foreach(Option.scala:257)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.handleTaskSetFailed(DAGScheduler.scala:802)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.doOnReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1650)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1605)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1594)
    at org.apache.spark.util.EventLoop$$anon$1.run(EventLoop.scala:48)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.runJob(DAGScheduler.scala:628)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:1925)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:1938)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:1951)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:1965)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$collect$1.apply(RDD.scala:936)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:151)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:112)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.withScope(RDD.scala:362)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.collect(RDD.scala:935)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.executeCollect(SparkPlan.scala:275)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.exchange.BroadcastExchangeExec$$anonfun$relationFuture$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(BroadcastExchangeExec.scala:78)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.exchange.BroadcastExchangeExec$$anonfun$relationFuture$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(BroadcastExchangeExec.scala:75)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withExecutionId(SQLExecution.scala:94)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.exchange.BroadcastExchangeExec$$anonfun$relationFuture$1.apply(BroadcastExchangeExec.scala:74)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.exchange.BroadcastExchangeExec$$anonfun$relationFuture$1.apply(BroadcastExchangeExec.scala:74)
    at scala.concurrent.impl.Future$PromiseCompletingRunnable.liftedTree1$1(Future.scala:24)
    at scala.concurrent.impl.Future$PromiseCompletingRunnable.run(Future.scala:24)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.util.NoSuchElementException: None.get
    at scala.None$.get(Option.scala:347)
    at scala.None$.get(Option.scala:345)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.StateStoreSaveExec$$anonfun$doExecute$3.apply(StatefulAggregate.scala:187)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.StateStoreSaveExec$$anonfun$doExecute$3.apply(StatefulAggregate.scala:148)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.state.StateStoreRDD.compute(StateStoreRDD.scala:64)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:323)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:287)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:38)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:323)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:287)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:38)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:323)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:287)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:38)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:323)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:287)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:87)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:99)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:322)
    ... 3 more
org.apache.spark.sql.streaming.StreamingQueryException: Exception thrown in awaitResult: 
=== Streaming Query ===
Identifier: [id = 60f7c698-7093-495a-bec8-5cdec7a06f69, runId = 6f533a5f-8891-4daf-bd21-79db292283c5]
Current Committed Offsets: {}
Current Available Offsets: {FileStreamSource[file:/C:/Users/ffff/Documents/f/ff/fff/ffff]: {"logOffset":0}}

Current State: ACTIVE
Thread State: RUNNABLE
```

#### More details

The same code works fine if I eliminate streaming and only use read(). I am able to make the second join on viewThree if I switch out the word the viewTwo to viewThree. I am not able to understand why this error is coming as it seems to me everything is in order. Any help is appreciated. I'm using eclipse and Spark 2.11.

### EDIT

I found that the reason it was giving the error was because of the drop duplicates line. Once I removed that, it worked with streaming. Can anyone explain why that would cause the exception I got and a work-around so that I can drop duplicates and still be able to join my streamed table.

Answer (score 0):

My theory is that the lazy evaluation mechanism is not playing along with the StreamView (maybe the sql call doesn't trigger the evaluation).

You can try to force the dropDuplicates to be evaluated by calling a "count" or some other action on dfTwo (right after the drop should be fine).